# Why doesn't std::string have a constructor that takes std::string_view?

Tags: c++, string-view

```
    // std::string_view vv("")
    // std::string ss = vv; // error
    // std::string ss(vv); // error
    std::string ss;
    ss = std::string_view(""); // ok, 'cause operator=(const StringViewLike&) is available
```

Is there a rational for this? Or is it just another thing that hasn't made into the standard yet?

---

The premise is false as is pointed out, that an explicit constructor exists.

Now I think the benifit is that the caller of a function should know copying happens to this `std::string_view` he's passing, while `std::string(const char*)` is often overlooked.

Comment: There are two `std::string` [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that take a "StringViewLike" argument (see alternative 10 and 11 in the linked reference).

Comment: string_view has begin()/end() and std::string can be constructed from that. `template<class InputIt basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

Comment: By the way this is a nice example of type erasure. The std::string constructor is based on what the other class can do not what type is is. In this case provide a begin and end iterator. In the end it allows for more reusable (less coupled) code. The only thing you need to do is call the correct constructor explicitly. (Which is good, implicit conversions have their own issues)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My bad. I tried `std::string ss = vv` in my C++17 code base and assumed there was no constructor for that.

Comment: Ah, that would use the alternative 10, which is marked as `explicit`, which explains the problem you have. :)

Comment: @Eljay I noticed this when I couldn't pass `std::string_view` to a `std::string` parameter, and I didn't know `std::string(const StringViewLike&) existed`. Now I guess simply passing `std::string(vv)` would do.